# Storing REST response to indexedDB with Cycle.js

Tags: cyclejs, xstream-js

I'm in the middle of learninig Cycle.JS and ran into a challenge. I have a component that will get a result from an HTTP call and I'd like to persist this response in indexDB. However, I feel that the request for persistence is the responsibility of another component.

The questions I have are:

1. Is this a use case for a custom driver that persists HTTP responses to indexDB?
2. How does another component access the response stream for a request it did not make?
3. When I try to select the category from the HTTP source, nothing gets logged to the console. I'm using xstream, so the streams should be hot and I expect debug to output. What's going on here?

Below is my component that makes the HTTP call:

```
import { Feed } from './feed'

export function RssList ({HTTP, props}, feedAdapter = x => x) {
  const request$ = props.url$
    .map(url => ({
      url: url,
      method: 'GET',
      category: 'rss'
    }))

  const response$ = HTTP
    .select('rss')
    .flatten()
    .map(feedAdapter)

  const vDom$ = response$
    .map(Feed)
    .startWith('')

  return {
    DOM: vDom$,
    HTTP: request$
  }
}
```

Here is my attempt at accessing the response at the app level:

```
export function main (sources) {
  const urlSource = url$(sources)
  const rssSink = rss$(sources, urlSource.value)

  const vDom$ = xs.combine(urlSource.DOM, rssSink.DOM)
    .map(([urlInput, rssList]) =>
      <div>
        {urlInput}
        {rssList}
      </div>
    )

  sources.HTTP.select('rss').flatten().debug() // nothing happens here

  return {
    DOM: vDom$,
    HTTP: rssSink.HTTP
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Selecting a category in the main (the parent) component is the correct approach, and is supported.

The only reason why `sources.HTTP.select('rss').flatten().debug()` doesn't log anything is because that's not how `debug` works. It doesn't "subscribe" to the stream and create side effects. `debug` is essentially like a `map` operator that uses an identity function (always takes `x` as input and outputs `x`), but with a logging operation as a side effect. So you either need to replace `.debug()` with `.addListener({next: x => console.log(x)})` or use the stream that `.debug()` outputs and hook it with the operator pipeline that goes to sinks. In other words, `debug` is an *in-between* logging side effect, not a *destination* logging side effect.

Answer (score 1):

Question #1: Custom HTTP->IDB Driver: It depends on the nature of the project, for a simple example I used a general [CycleJS IDB Driver](https://github.com/cyclejs-community/cycle-idb). See example below or [codesandbox.io example.](https://codesandbox.io/s/z3704kv8wl)

Question #2: Components Sharing Streams: Since components and `main` share the same source/sink API you can link the output (`sink`) of one component to the input (`source`) of another. See example below or [codesandbox.io example.](https://codesandbox.io/s/z3704kv8wl)

Question #3: `debug` and Logging: As the authoritative ([literally](https://survivejs.com/blog/cycle-interview/)) [André](https://github.com/staltz) [Staltz](https://twitter.com/andrestaltz/) pointed out `debug` needs to be inserted into a completed stream cycle, I.E., an already subscribed/listened stream.

In your example you can put `debug` in your `RssList` component:

```js
const response$ = HTTP
  .select('rss')
  .flatten()
  .map(feedAdapter)
  .debug()
```

OR add a listener to your `main` example:

```js
sources.HTTP.select('rss').flatten().debug()
  .addListener({next: x => console.log(x)})
```

OR, what I like to do, is include a log driver:

```js
run(main, {
    DOM: makeDOMDriver('#app'),
    HTTP: makeHTTPDriver(),
    log: log$ => log$.addListener({next: log => console.log(log)}),
})
```

Then I'll just duplicate a stream and send it to the `log` sink:

```js
const url$ = props.url
const http$ = url$.map(url => ({url: url, method: 'GET', category: 'rss'}))
const log$ = url$

return {
  DOM: vdom$,
  HTTP: http$,
  log: log$,
}
```

---

Here's some example code for sending HTTP response to IndexedDB storage, using two components that share the data and a general IndexedDB driver:

```js
function main(sources) {
  const header$ = xs.of(div('RSS Feed:'))

  const rssSink = RssList(sources) // input HTTP select and props
                                   // output VDOM and data for IDB storage
  const vDom$ = xs.combine(header$, rssSink.DOM) // build VDOM
    .map(([header, rssList]) => div([header, rssList])
  )
  const idbSink = IdbSink(sources, rssSink.IDB) // output store and put HTTP response

  return {
    DOM: vDom$,
    HTTP: rssSink.HTTP, // send HTTP request
    IDB: idbSink.put, // send response to IDB store
    log: idbSink.get, // get and log data stored in IDB
  }
}

function RssList({ HTTP, props }, feedAdapter = x => x) {
  const request$ = props.url$
    .map(url => ({url: url, method: 'GET', category: 'rss'}))

  const response$ = HTTP.select('rss').flatten().map(feedAdapter)
  const idb$ = response$
  const vDom$ = response$
    .map(Feed)
    .startWith(div('','...loading'))

  return {
    DOM: vDom$,
    HTTP: request$,
    IDB: { response: idb$ },
  }
}
function Feed (feed) {
  return div('> ' + feed)
}

function IdbSink(sources, idb) {
  return {
    get: sources.IDB.store('rss').getAll()
      .map(obj => (obj['0'] && obj['0'].feed) || 'unknown'),
    put: idb.response
      .map(feedinfo => $put('rss', { feed: feedinfo }))
  }
}

run(main, {
  props: () => ({ url$: xs.of('http://lorem-rss.herokuapp.com/feed') }),
  DOM: makeDOMDriver('#root'),
  HTTP: makeHTTPDriver(),
  IDB: makeIdbDriver('rss-db', 1, upgradeDb => {
    upgradeDb.createObjectStore('rss', { keyPath: 'feed' })
  }),
  log: log$ => log$.addListener({next: log => console.log(log)}),
})
```

This is a contrived example, simply to explore the issues raised. [Codesandbox.io example.](https://codesandbox.io/s/z3704kv8wl)